# Which tags worth to select to my question?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question that i.e. closely belongs to a technology like Apple's `MKMapKit` and broadly to `iOS`, then should I use both or it is enough to use `MKMapKit`?

Normaly I use both of the tag, or because in my understanding knowledge can be described like a tree, I use tags that are on the same branch on a tree. If you understand what I meant. But most of the time it is overkill. `MKMapKit` relating questions are to specific for to understand someone who know only `iOS` but not `MKMapKit` API.

[How to get notified when MKMapKit zoom level changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998414/who-to-get-a-notification-when-mkmapkit-zoom-level-changed)

Comment: Read the tag's description/wiki.  It's there specifically to help you determine if they apply to your question.